# Number of strings with one element as the most common element

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, combinatorics-on-words

> Consider the number of strings formed from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ of length
> $n$.
>
> What is the number of strings in which the number of occurrence of
> $1$ is greater or equal to the number of occurrence of any other
> number?

I'm wondering how can we use the generating function to solve this? Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Hint: condition on the number $k$ of $1$s, yielding recurrence $a_n=\sum_k \binom{n}{k} b_{n-k,k}$, where $b_{n,k}$ is the number of strings of length $n$ on $\{2,3,4,5\}$ with at most $k$ occurrences of any number.

Comment: But then can we find a simple formula for −,?

Comment: I just realized that there might be more than one interpretation of *any other* here, and one interpretation seems to yield a much harder problem than the other.  What are the allowed strings for $n=3$?

Comment: I think it should be strings like 123, 133, 112, 145 and so on.

Comment: can you explain why $133$ is there? When you say any, do you really mean some? In this case, this some is either $2,4$ or $5$?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. I actually mean 113

Comment: "and so on": please enumerate them all or at least provide a count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick the numbers of $1'$s that you want(This is RobPratt hint) say $k$ and then consider the number of $j'$s as $n_j,$ we want them to be such that $0\leq n_j\leq k$ and also we want them all of this occurrences to add up to $n$.

$$\sum _{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\sum _{\substack{n_2+n_3+n_4+n_5=n-k\\n_j\leq k}}\binom{n-k}{n_2,n_3,n_4,n_5}=n!\sum _{k=1}^n\sum _{\substack{n_2+n_3+n_4+n_5+k=n\\n_j\leq k}}\frac{1}{n_2!\,n_3!\,n_4!\,n_5!\,k!}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that seems to make a lot of sense. But is there any way for us to further simplify the second sum?

Comment: Well, i would say that this is not easy since this last sum you can think of it as being the coefficient of $n-k$ in $$\left(\sum _{i=0}^k\frac{x^i}{i!}\right ) ^4$$ but this i doubt it has a nice expression.